# Enum Memory Usage

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to know which of the following occupies more memory

```
struct Constants
{
    var age = 10
}
```

or

```
enum Constants
{
    case age = 10
}
```

I also wanted to know the difference between `enum` and `#define` in terms of memory storage. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Why don't you check it yourself with `sizeof(Constants)` ?

Answer (score 12):

#### TLDR

Your struct would occupy the size of an Int, so on a recent Mac platform 64 bits (8 bytes).
Your enumeration would normally occupy the size of an UInt8 so 8 bits (1 byte) but in this special case of a one case enum the size is 0 bit.

---

#### To understand that, here is some detail

An enumeration internally stores an integer value to match the cases against.

For instance this enum:

```swift
enum Direction {
    case east, west, south, north
}
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```swift
struct Direction {
    private var rawValue: UInt8
    
    private init(_ rawValue: UInt8) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }

    static var east: Direction { Direction(0) }
    static var west: Direction { Direction(1) }
    static var south: Direction { Direction(2) }
    static var north: Direction { Direction(3) }
}
```

with some auto-generated methods to enable use in `switch` and if blocks, and some compiler magic to support switch statements exhaustivity.

**Note that the rawValue is `UInt8` so any Swift enumeration with less than 256 cases and without any associated value is 8 bits (1 byte).**

If your enumeration has more than 255 cases the `rawValue` type upgrades to `UInt16`, and so on.

An enum containing an associated value is much more memory consuming, its size is the size of the rawValue + the size of the largest associated values.

For instance:

```swift
enum Shape {
    case circle(radius: Double)
    case rectangle(width: Double, height: Double)
}
```

This enum would be 136bits (17bytes): 2 * size(`Double`) + size(`UInt8`) because the rectangle case has the largest associated values which are two `Double`s.

**In your case you defined an enum with custom raw values of type `Int`. Contrary to an enum with associated values this does not change the size of the enum at all.** The Compiler just synthesises a computed property that return the custom `rawValue`.

For instance this enum with a String `rawValue` is still 1byte:

```swift
enum HelloWorld: String {
    case hello = "Hello, "
    case world = "world!"
}

// "Equivalent" to...
enum HelloWorld {
    case hello
    case world

    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .hello:
            return "Hello, "
        case .world:
            return "world!"
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Note 1

You can check the size of anything with:

```
MemoryLayout<TypeToSize>.size  // for a type
MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: yourValue)  /* for an instance */
```

Be careful with reference types though, for instance a class is a reference type so it has the size of a pointer so 64 bits (8 bytes) on recent Mac platforms.

---

#### Note 2

If your enumeration has lots of heavy associated types you can turn it into a reference type with the `indirect` keyword so its size is one of a pointer but this cost you the dereferencing operation.

---

#### Note 3

**In Swift the proper way to create a namespace is to define an enum with no case and only static properties.**

The advantage of an enum over a struct is that such an enum **cannot be instantiated** which is the indented behaviour for a namespace.

In your case the proper way is:

```swift
enum Constants {
    static var age = 10
}

// Example of use...
let birthYear = 2020 - Constants.age
```

An empty enum or an enum with only one case has a size of 0 bit. However, the static property needs to be stored at some point, this cost you at least the size of the `Int` value.

---

#### Note 4

`#define` only exists in Objective-C AFAIK, not in Swift, so the canonic way to replicate this pattern is through the case-less enum (avoid global variables).

Answer (score 3):

A `#define` is more or less an exact copy of the text you put in the define. That means if a `#define` contains a block of code then that block will be compiled on every place where the defined value is used.

```
#define sqare_2 sqrt(2.0)
```

Would be a bad idea since every time you would call `sqare_2` it would actually call the `sqrt` function and not remember the result. Well, unless a compile time optimization is made but I hope you get the picture. So a `#define` has nothing to do with the memory as it is compile time directive, not runtime.

Enumerations in Swift are pure OOP and are much like a class. It will add a lot of methods such as `rawValue` which makes the element quite large, bad on performance and may have extra memory consumption but probably not per instance. The enumeration works as if it only had static methods so creating instances should not inflate memory beyond to that the type of the raw value of the enumeration.

A structure takes as much memory as you define in it plus the memory for the pointers which in small structures represent most of the data. A number of these pointers and the actual size may vary from the implementations of the Swift. For instance if the language supports swizzling it generally means that each class or structure will contain pointers to functions which are its methods. If so we would expect each method written will add at least 32 or 64 bits to the size of the object and this also applies to the methods received from the superclass. And since some methods are already there such as a compare it will always take extra memory. And since new versions are added you may expect the size to vary.

I am sorry I do not have an answer for your specific case to say which is larger and it might be you will never find the answer to that. But in general the size of an object is very hard to find. For instance you would probably get that the size of the `String` is always only the size of the pointer. If you unwrapped it though you might find that it has a size of 3 pointers and 3 integers but again the size is constant no matter the length of the string. The reason for that is again one of the pointers holds the actual string data while the rest are there for things such as encoding, length... You could argue that it is obvious that the string is the owner of the actual text data and should include those data in size but then what about the wrappers: Should the size of the `UILabel` depend on its text length? And if so what happens when 2 labels share the same text; then the sum of sizes would be larger then the actual memory consumption.