# How I can build a custom Type without using any other Swift Type in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums

What I am trying to find out and learn is that how I could build a custom Type, for example I created this simple enum called **Allowed**, which has 2 cases **Yes** and **No**, and I would like to use it as real Type like Bool Type, and in the other hand I do not want just inherit Bool Type to this custom Type. How I can do that? beside this question I think this custom Type should confirm to "==" and "!=" for if statement, and Size of this type is 1 bit.

```
enum Allowed { case Yes, No }
```

---

use case:

```
let result: Allowed = Allowed.No
```

My Goal use case:

```
let result: Allowed = No
```

Comment: As a matter of convention, enum cases are usually in lower case: `enum Allowed { case yes, no }` and `let result: Allowed = .no`. And as convenient as the `enum` is, in this situation most of us would use `Bool` (as does Apple in their API). Now if you had more than two cases, then a custom `enum` would be logical. But `let result = false` seems like best practice in this particular example, eliminating the need for the custom `enum`.

Comment: Here's a writeup on [enum sizes in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60948825/3791245), which may help with your sub-question about the enum size.  (TL;DR is that for only 2 cases, an instance of your enum should take up only 1 byte.)

Comment: @SeanSkelly, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// To get == and !=, conform to Hashable
enum Allowed: Hashable {
    case yes, no // I recommend using standard naming conventions
}

let Yes = Allowed.yes  // But as global constants, capitals are probably clearer
let No = Allowed.no

let result = No // No need to include a type
```

As Sean notes, a two value enum will be one byte.

(I don't recommend this particular set of names, but the general approach is fine.)

---

To your question in the comments, if you want `init()` to initialized this to `.no`, then you would need to write that initializer:

```
extension Allowed {
    init() { self = .no }
}

let answer: Allowed = Allowed()
```

Comment: I don't understand. How is this not a type? I didn't mean this to be a hack; this is how you create values. Are you trying to create a new keyword? (That's not possible)

Comment: I am sorry! then you just created a real custom type now? I am just learning here

Comment: Yes. This is just as real a type as Bool. Bool's just a struct, built with fairly standard code: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Bool.swift (I don't think you can't 100% reproduce Bool, but you can come very, very close.)

Comment: why I can not use this code if this way is a type? ***let answer: Allowed = Allowed()*** how I can give No as default init() for this type?

Answer (score 2):

Actually in swift you can omit the enum type as compiler can infer it:

```
let result: Allowed = .No
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I know the infer topic, I would like without "."

Comment: @Omid It might help if you explained what your actual use case is for this and why you don't want to use the built-in language features for it.